# .NET Core - How to upload JSON file?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-core

I am trying to upload JSON file in order to read values from it and save them in database, but I have problem with that. Code of my controller looks as following:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ImportController : ControllerBase
{

    private readonly DatabaseContext dbContext;

    public ImportController(DatabaseContext dbContext)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult ImportData(IFormFile file)
    {
        var content = string.Empty;

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream()))
        {
            content = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        List<UserModel> userObjects = null;
        try
        {
            userObjects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UserModel>>(content);
        }
        catch
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        foreach (var user in userObjects)
        {

             UserModel us = new UserModel
             {
                 Username = user.Username,
                 Password = user.Password
             };

             dbContext.User.Add(us);
             dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }

        return Ok();
    }

}
```

I'm using Postman to send JSON data, but anytime I try to do it, I get following response:

> {"Username":["The input was not valid."]}

when I try to send JSON data as raw->application/json OR

> {"":["The input was not valid."]}

when I try to send it by form-data with key called "file" and test.json file as value.

Could you direct me to the right path? I tried to use `[FromBody] UserModel user` as parameter of my action, but it only allows me to process one JSON string.

Comment: So, you are not uploading a file, but you are actually POSTing it in your request. Show your request example and what is your request when "it only allows me to process one JSON string".

Comment: make sure you use `multipart/form-data` in postman and it's POST

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev - this (https://imgur.com/a/LKiUPPR) is example of my request, I changed code according to answer of AlexRiabov and now it works fine when I try to POST many JSON values but it doesn't work when I try to do the same using file instead of raw application/json in Postman. And yeah, by "it  only allows me to process one JSON string" I meant that doesn't matter how many JSON values I tried to pass, only first one was read. But this issue is fixed now.
Konrad - it's POST and I tried to use multipart/form-data, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[FromBody] IEnumerable<UserModel> users` to process many rows. In this case json should look like:

```
[
 {
  "userName": "name",
  "password": "password",
 },
 {
  "userName": "name1",
  "password": "password1",
 }
]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This solution works perfectly fine when I try to POST JSON in first way but I still got the same error when I try to do it in second way (as you can see on this screenshot: https://imgur.com/bcfHzZf). JSON strings are the same in both cases and Traces says `Executing ObjectResult, writing value of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.SerializableError'.`

Comment: @Kamil but why do you need it in second way?

Comment: in my app I will need upload form, using which user can choose JSON file and import data from it.

Comment: @Kamil can't you read the file on client and send it in body?

Answer (score 1):

You need to standardize your approach one way or another. If you want to accept JSON, then bind to an action param of type `List<UserViewModel>` with the `[FromBody]` attribute, and client-side, use JavaScript's `FileReader` to get the actual content of the upload loaded file and post the content, rather than the file.

If you want to do it by file upload, then you can keep the action as it is, but you'll need to then send your own "JSON" as a file upload as well. This can be achieved by using `FormData` in JavaScript and creating a `Blob` manually from your JSON object as a string.

Long and short, whichever path you choose, be uniform about it. There's no way to handle both posting a JSON object and a file upload that happens to be a text file with a `.json` extension in the same action.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it... All I had to do was deleting `[ApiController]` attribute. Having that attribute caused application to didn't visit my ImportData method at all.